# Existence of Ring Object

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category with finite products and a terminal object $T$. Then the category has a natural ring object, namely the terminal object. My question is if there are some good conditions to assume the existence of a non-trivial ring object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic reason the category of sets has many ring objects is that set-based rings can be given by presentations. If $\mathcal C$ has countable coproducts and coequalizers (equivalently, all countable colimits) and the finite products commute with them, then the forgetful functor from ring objects in $\mathcal C$ admits a left adjoint, giving free rings. If $\mathcal C$ also has reasonable exactness properties—I think regularity will suffice—then its category of ring objects will have coequalizers, so the whole theory of ring presentations works smoothly. The assumption that finite products commute with coproducts can probably be loosened here, possibly at the cost of adding some colimits if transfinite chains to the construction of free rings.

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure this really gives a satisfying answer to the question. After all, if there are no non-trivial ring objects in $C$, then the forgetful functor from the category of ring objects in $C$ to $C$ has a left adjoint! So we have free ring objects and even ring presentations, but every ring object presented by generators and relations is trivial.

Comment: In other words, there are two components (1) the theory of rings presented by generators and relations, and (2) the existence of a non-trivial ring, which *together* give rise to lots of rings in Set. And I think the question being asked here is really about (2).

Comment: @AlexKruckman Great point. I believe that when free rings exist according to the construction above, the unit of the free ring monad will always be a monomorphism. In the simpler setting of monoids, this is just the observation that the canonical inclusion of $x$ into $\sqcup x^k$ is a monomorphism. I'm a bit nervous I might need to assume extensivity as well to get this to work, but I'm not immediately sure.

Comment: @KevinArlin Thanks for your answer. Indeed, my question is really more directed towards (2) of the comment by Alex Kruckman.

Comment: @curiousmathguy As I said to Alex, as long as coproduct inclusions in the base category are monomorphisms, free rings on each object will be distinct.